# Macro Action: How to select a specific column or a specific range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macro-recorder

I want to create a macro in Google Sheets where part of the macro involves Selecting Column E, or selecting rows 2-1000. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**select cell A2 and use:**

> Selecting Column E

```
function Macro1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn() + 4, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).activate();
};
```

---

> selecting rows 2-1000

```
function Macro2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
};
```

Comment: thanks! sorry I'm kind of confused on how this works though, how would I adjust it to Column V or Rows 3-150?

Comment: you change +4 to correspond with V column number in a first macro and for 2nd macro it would be selecting A3 and using this: `function Macro3() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow(), 1, 148, sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
};`